# leave and enter animation on one component with react.js

Tags: animation, reactjs

I am having problems handling enter and leaving animations for a single element with react.js.
It works on a collection of elements using ReactTransitionGroup, but doesn't work for a single element because componentWillLeave is never triggered.  When I fetch new data from the server, and there is only one element to be rendered, the animation doesn't work.

Comment: Please include relevant code.

Comment: Also please specify what errors or problems you are encountering (what specifically goes wrong when you use ReactTransitionGroup).  If you could include a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem, that would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you've specified `key` in the animated element - you have to do it even if there's only one.